# Issue with loading a URL with post in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a coredova based iOS application and trying to load a URL on a `UIWebView`. For example:

`http://www.something.com`

This URL loads without any issue but the problem is when I tap on the submit button on the loaded page after entering an email in the text field. This is a POST request but the request never reach the server.

On submit, Call back comes to below delegate method with navigation type as 
`UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted` and the `request HTTPBody` contains the email entered by the user. This delegate method just return YES.

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

After this, I get below success callback but the screen still remains in the old screen itself.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Please help me finding the reason for this issue.

Also, note that the same URL works fine when I load in any browser.

Comment: do you return YES from shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method?

Comment: Yes. I am returning YES.

Comment: is it classic http form or maybe there exists some javascript logic on submit?

Comment: Javascript logic exist but it is just doing page validation.

Comment: may be it's crashing inside due to some specific Safari engine feature. I would recommend to attach to javascript console right on device or in simulator via OS X Safari and see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 9 all requests with HTTP are forbidden and HTTPS should be used.

There is a workaround though for this if you really need to use HTTP.

Add this to your .plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqs5D.png)

Comment: The author said that first page is loading well, so it's not the issue with transport security